# Error when trying to open a webpage with mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to learn mechanize to create a chat logging bot later, so I tested out some basic code

```py
import mechanize as mek
import re

br = mek.Browser()
br.open("google.com")
```

However, whenever I run it, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 262, in _mech_open
    url.get_full_url
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_full_url'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    br.open("google.com")
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 253, in open
    return self._mech_open(url_or_request, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 269, in _mech_open
    raise BrowserStateError("can't fetch relative reference: "
mechanize._mechanize.BrowserStateError: can't fetch relative reference: not viewing any document
```

I double checked with the documentation on the mechanize page and it seems consistent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a schema, otherwise mechanize thinks you are trying to open a local/relative path (as the error suggests).

`br.open("google.com")` should be `br.open("http://google.com")`.

Then you will see an error `mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: b'request disallowed by robots.txt'`, because `google.com` does not allow crawlers. This can be remedied with `br.set_handle_robots(False)` before `open`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that! (although google cant actually be read due to a robots.txt haha)

Comment: @Anadactothe See updated answer, that can also be fixed